# FastHttp server "removes" Authorization header

Tags: go, authorization, httprequest, fasthttp

**Edit:** Fixed. To see what was wrong take a look at [this](https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp/issues/723).

When I try to send a request to a FastHttp server with an Authorization header, the header gets removed. When I send a request with Postman, the Authorization header does not get removed.

To see what headers are actually sent I set up a Undertow web server (Java) and sent my requests to that server.

Code of the Java webserver:

```java
Undertow undertow = Undertow.builder().addHttpListener(55446, "localhost", new HttpHandler() {
    public void handleRequest(final HttpServerExchange httpServerExchange) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Con from "+httpServerExchange.getHostName());
        System.out.println("Query "+httpServerExchange.getQueryString());
        System.out.println("Header "+httpServerExchange.getRequestHeaders().getHeaderNames().stream().map(str -> str.toString()+": "+httpServerExchange.getRequestHeaders().get(str).element()).collect(Collectors.joining("; ")));
        httpServerExchange.getRequestReceiver().receiveFullString((httpServerExchange1, s) -> System.out.println("Body "+s));

        httpServerExchange.setStatusCode(400);
    }
}).build();
undertow.start();
```

Output when I send the request with Postman:

```
------------------------------------------
Con from localhost
Query 
Header Accept: */*; Postman-Token: 275ba9bb-77cc-4c9f-baa5-653f60162551; Connection: keep-alive; Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; Cache-Control: no-cache; Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate; User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.21.0; Host: localhost:55446
Body
```

Output when I send the request with my application:

```
------------------------------------------
Con from localhost
Query 
Header test: f; Accept: application/json, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, application/xml, text/xml; Authorization: Bearer testtoken; Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate; User-Agent: VSpedSync/DevBuild; Host: localhost:55446
Body
```

In both cases the Authorization header is sent, but when I send the requests to the FastHttp server only the one from Postman contains the header.

Im so confused, why exactly is this happening?

Comment: Please share the relevant portions of your FastHttp server source so we can see how you are retrieving the headers (a minimal viable example will help here; you show the java code that works but not the golang code that does not).

Comment: @Brits The server source code can be found here: https://github.com/VirtualSped/backend
Im using the /auth/check endpoint.